# Possible rotate image printer zebra

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I Have the following code:

`^FO005,041^XGDILOGO01,2,2^FS`

prints from the vertical, how can I do to print horizontally??

Comment: Why don't you rotate the image before sending it to the printer?

Comment: thnx @banno , sometimes the solution is much more simple than you'd think :D

Answer (score 2):

The individual field orientation in your label for text and barcodes are specified in the fourth letter of ^AON and ^BCN commands. To change the orientation of any of these fields, use the appropriate letter from following list:

- N = normal
- R = rotated 90 degrees (clockwise)
- I = inverted 180 degrees
- B = read from bottom up, 270 degrees

For example, to print the barcode at 90 degrees, replace ^BCN,.... to ^BCR,..., or to print a particular text line at 90 degrees, replace ^AON,... to ^AOR,....

To change the default orientation of all fields in your label, you can use ^FWx before any text / barcode fields are called out, where x represents the desired default orientation (from above list of orientation options), and only include the orientation letter in individual text / barcode commands (i.e., change ^BCN,... to ^BC,... and ^AON,... to ^AO,...) for any exceptions to that default orientation.

Also, you will need to adjust the x/y coordinates once you change field orientation.

Comment: it does not answer the question, does it?